# IEnumerable<object[]> not returning missing or null XML elements

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, ienumerable

With this current project, I am reading through 1000-1700 XML files and extracting information. The issue that I am currently facing is that not all of the XMLs are clean. Some are missing key elements that the IEnumerable is looking for or the data is just empty values. My problem is that I am unable to account for these missing or NULL values. I have tried `string.Empty` and `string.IsNullOrEmpty` but intellisense isn't liking it. My thought process that if the element is missing or returns null, have those values to equal "NA". Am I off base with my way of thinking?

```
private static IEnumerable<object[]> GetDocumentsData(string folderPath = @"filepath")
{

return Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xml")
.Select(XDocument.Load)
.SelectMany(file => file.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "FilingLeadDocument")
.Concat(file.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "FilingConnectedDocument")))
.Select(documentNode =>
{
try
{
var receivedDateNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentReceivedDate");
var SequenceNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentSequenceID");
var descriptionNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentDescriptionText");
var metadataNode = documentNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentMetadata");
var registerActionNode = metadataNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "RegisterActionDescriptionText");

return new object[]
{
(string)documentNode.Parent.Parent.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentIdentification"),
SequenceNode != null ? SequenceNode.Value.Trim() : string.Empty,
(DateTime?)receivedDateNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DateTime"),
descriptionNode != null ? descriptionNode.Value.Trim() : string.Empty,
registerActionNode != null ? registerActionNode.Value.Trim() : string.Empty
};
}
catch (Exception e)
{
//Log.error("");
return new object[] { };
}
}).ToArray();
}
```

XML Example (`RegisterActionDescriptionText` element is missing from XML)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<RecordFilingRequest xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:wsdl:WebServiceMessagingProfile-Definitions-4.0">
  <RecordFilingRequestMessage xmlns:fsrsp="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:FilingStatusResponseMessage-4.0" xmlns:ecf="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0" xmlns:j="http://niem.gov/niem/domains/jxdm/4.0" xmlns:juvenile="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:JuvenileCase-4.0" xmlns:niem-xsd="http://niem.gov/niem/proxy/xsd/2.0" xmlns:domestic="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:DomesticCase-4.0" xmlns:s="http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0" xmlns:criminal="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CriminalCase-4.0" xmlns:amcadext="http://www.amcad.com/NiemEcf/extensions/1.0" xmlns:i="http://niem.gov/niem/appinfo/2.0" xmlns:appellate="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:AppellateCase-4.0" xmlns:nc="http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0" xmlns:citation="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CitationCase-4.0" xmlns:reviewcb="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:ReviewFilingCallbackMessage-4.0" xmlns:civil="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CivilCase-4.0">
    <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="ReviewWorkQueueId">484</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
    <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="ReviewWorkQueue">Criminal Traffic Existing Cases</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
    <nc:DocumentIdentification>
      <nc:IdentificationID>14115049</nc:IdentificationID>
    </nc:DocumentIdentification>
    <nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DateTime>2014-05-28T10:17:05.229345-04:00</nc:DateTime>
    </nc:DocumentPostDate>
    <nc:DocumentSubmitter>
      <ecf:EntityPerson s:id="REVIEWER">
        <nc:PersonName>
          <nc:PersonGivenName>re</nc:PersonGivenName>
          <nc:PersonSurName>re</nc:PersonSurName>
          <nc:PersonFullName>re</nc:PersonFullName>
        </nc:PersonName>
        <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>51201</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
        <nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
          <nc:IdentificationID>re</nc:IdentificationID>
          <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_LOGONNAME</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
        </nc:PersonOtherIdentification>
        <ecf:PersonAugmentation>
          <nc:ContactInformation>
            <nc:ContactEmailID>re</nc:ContactEmailID>
            <nc:ContactMailingAddress>
              <nc:StructuredAddress>
                <nc:AddressDeliveryPointText>re</nc:AddressDeliveryPointText>
                <nc:LocationCityName>re</nc:LocationCityName>
                <nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>FL</nc:LocationStateUSPostalServiceCode>
                <nc:LocationStateName>FL</nc:LocationStateName>
              </nc:StructuredAddress>
              <nc:AddressFullText>re</nc:AddressFullText>
            </nc:ContactMailingAddress>
          </nc:ContactInformation>
        </ecf:PersonAugmentation>
      </ecf:EntityPerson>
    </nc:DocumentSubmitter>
    <ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
      <nc:IdentificationID>Filing Review MDE</nc:IdentificationID>
    </ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
    <ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:WebServicesMessaging-2.0</ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>
    <CoreFilingMessage xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CoreFilingMessage-4.0">
      <nc:DocumentEffectiveDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2014-05-28T08:00:00-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentEffectiveDate>
      <nc:DocumentIdentification>
        <nc:IdentificationID>14115049</nc:IdentificationID>
        <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_FILING_ID</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
      </nc:DocumentIdentification>
      <nc:DocumentInformationCutOffDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2014-05-27T17:50:51.297-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentInformationCutOffDate>
      <nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2014-05-27T18:45:13.8464904-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentPostDate>
      <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DateTime>2014-05-27T17:50:51.297-04:00</nc:DateTime>
      </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
      <ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
        <nc:IdentificationID>URL/UNIQUE IDENTIFIER OF APPLICATION SENDING THIS REQUEST</nc:IdentificationID>
        <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
      </ecf:SendingMDELocationID>
      <ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:WebServicesMessaging-2.0</ecf:SendingMDEProfileCode>
      <criminal:Case>
        <nc:ActivityDescriptionText s:id="Criminal Traffic">re</nc:ActivityDescriptionText>
        <nc:CaseTitleText>re</nc:CaseTitleText>
        <nc:CaseCategoryText s:id="40781916535">831</nc:CaseCategoryText>
        <nc:CaseTrackingID>052014CT</nc:CaseTrackingID>
        <nc:CaseTrackingID s:id="ucn">052014CT</nc:CaseTrackingID>
        <j:CaseAugmentation>
          <j:CaseCourt>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>05</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_ORGANIZATION</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>28</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>FLEPORTAL_ORGANIZATION_UNIT</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>Trial</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>COURT_TYPE</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationIdentification>
              <nc:IdentificationID>Eighteenth Circuit</nc:IdentificationID>
              <nc:IdentificationCategoryText>JUDICIAL_CIRCUIT_ID</nc:IdentificationCategoryText>
            </nc:OrganizationIdentification>
            <nc:OrganizationName>re</nc:OrganizationName>
            <nc:OrganizationUnitName>Criminal Traffic</nc:OrganizationUnitName>
            <j:CourtName>Criminal Traffic</j:CourtName>
          </j:CaseCourt>
        </j:CaseAugmentation>
      </criminal:Case>
      <FilingLeadDocument s:id="DOC00001">
        <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
        <nc:DocumentDescriptionText>CLASS EMPTY-CS-AAADH6K-CE- 1AAADH6K</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
        <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="DocumentGroup">MOTIONS</nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
        <nc:DocumentDescriptionText s:id="DocumentType">MOTION TO SUPRESS                                                                         </nc:DocumentDescriptionText>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="FileInputId">101</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6PublicAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="Rule6ConfidentialAnswer">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentFileControlID s:id="TypeOfConfidentialDocument">-1</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
        <nc:DocumentPostDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2014-05-27T18:45:13.8464904-04:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentPostDate>
        <nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
          <nc:DateTime>2014-05-27T17:50:51.297-04:00</nc:DateTime>
        </nc:DocumentReceivedDate>
        <nc:DocumentSequenceID>1</nc:DocumentSequenceID>
        <ecf:DocumentRendition>
          <ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
            <nc:DocumentApplicationName>application/pdf</nc:DocumentApplicationName>
            <nc:DocumentFileControlID>Class EMPTY-CS-AAADH6K-CE- 1AAADH6K.PDF</nc:DocumentFileControlID>
            <ecf:DocumentAttachment s:id="ATT00001">
              <nc:BinaryBase64Object>removed by RB </nc:BinaryBase64Object>
              <nc:BinarySizeValue>101864</nc:BinarySizeValue>
              <ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>1</ecf:AttachmentSequenceID>
            </ecf:DocumentAttachment>
          </ecf:DocumentRenditionMetadata>
        </ecf:DocumentRendition>
      </FilingLeadDocument>
    </CoreFilingMessage>
 </RecordFilingRequestMessage>
</RecordFilingRequest>
```

Comment: What xml you are talking about? Which of these lines you have problem with?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy receivedDateNode,SequenceNode,descriptionNode,registerActionNode are not always in the XML but if they are, I am finding the values empty. I am trying to figure out how to accommodate for the missing Elements or where the value is null.

Comment: Can you provide sample xml and explain what data you want to extract?

Comment: I bet there should be definition of namespaces nc, ecf in your xml. Are you sure you have pasted whole xml?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy the full XML is now there.

Comment: OK, good. Now please explain what you are trying to get from this xml

Comment: Also its not clear why you are trying to return `IEnumerable<object[]>` instead of some custom data type with data parsed from xml file

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy From the Element named `FilingLeadDocument`, I am needing DocumentReceivedDate, DocumentSequenceID, DocumentDescriptionText and RegisterActionDescriptionText. The issue I have is that some of these elements are not ever showing up in the XML. Second, the reason I am doing it this way is because it loads all the XML data into the datagridview in the GUI

Comment: OK, I see. Writing solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to parse this xml, you have to deal with namespaces when searching elements by name. So, first thing you should do, is to get namespaces which you will need:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(fileName);
var ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();
XNamespace ecf = "urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0";
XNamespace nc = "http://niem.gov/niem/niem-core/2.0";
XNamespace s = "http://niem.gov/niem/structures/2.0";
XNamespace cfm = "urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CoreFilingMessage-4.0";
```

Next thing you will need is passing full name of elements to Linq methods instead of searching by local name (remember, Linq methods accept `XName` of element instead of simple string). So, if you need to `FilingLeadDocument` and its content

```
var fld = xdoc.Root.Element(ns + "RecordFilingRequestMessage")
              .Element(cfm + "CoreFilingMessage")
              .Element(cfm + "FilingLeadDocument");
```

Next goes reading values of elements that can be missing. If you would use `Value` property, then you'll get `NullReferenceException`. So, you should use casting of element instead. E.g. casting to string will return elements value or `null` if element is not found.

```
var fillingLeadDoc = new FillingLeadDoc {
    ReceivedDate = (DateTime?)fld.Elements(nc + "DocumentReceivedDate")
                                 .Elements(nc + "DateTime").FirstOrDefault(),
    SequenceId = (int?)fld.Element(nc + "DocumentSequenceID"),
    DescriptionText = (string)fld.Element(nc + "DocumentDescriptionText")
};
```

Where `FillingLeadDoc` is class

```
public class FillingLeadDoc
{
    public int? SequenceId { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReceivedDate { get; set; }
    public string DescriptionText { get; set; }
}
```

For your sample xml following instance will be created:

```
{
  SequenceId: 1,
  ReceivedDate: "2014-05-28T00:50:51.297+03:00",
  DescriptionText: "CLASS EMPTY-CS-AAADH6K-CE- 1AAADH6K"
}
```

Move this code to some `GetFillingLeadDoc` method:

```
private static FillingLeadDoc GetFillingLeadDoc(string fileName)
{
    // code above
    return fillingLeadDoc;
}
```

And call this method for each file:

```
private static IEnumerable<FillingLeadDoc> GetDocumentsData(
   string folderPath = @"filepath")
{
   return Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, "*.xml")
                   .Select(GetFillingLeadDoc);
}
```

Then bind your grid to these documents.

Comment: what happens if the element is not in the XML at all?

Comment: @clerktech which element?

Comment: for some reason, the ReceivedDate, SequenceID, DocumentDescriptionText or RegisterActionDescriptionText do not write to the XML. I need to still load this information into a databgridview with a default value of "NA".

Comment: @clerktech properties of FillingLeadDoc are nullable. So there will be null value if some element is missing. You can setup your DataGridView to display `NA` for null values (that is completely different question, out of this scope)

Comment: you sir are awesome!!! I will start reworking my entire program right now to incorporate your code. Why are there a million different ways for reading XML and which is the proper way? Was my current method good?

Comment: @clerktech basically there is two methods - sequential reading of xml (XmlReader) without building in-memory representation of xml tree, and loading all xml with tree building (XmlDocument and XDocument, latter one replaced old one). So, if files are not very big, your approach is completely OK.

Comment: question for you Sergey. I've been informed that I cannot rewrite this application using the above. `registerActionNode != null ? registerActionNode.Value.Trim() : "NA"` does work but doesn't account for when an element is missing. Ideas?

Comment: @clerktech what exactly you can't use? You can't change properties of DataGridView? If `registerActionNode != null ? registerActionNode.Value.Trim() : "NA"` does not work, then why you accepted that answer?

Comment: that's strange because I didn't change it (the accepted answer). change the properties of the DataGridView? in this in the properties or hard coded? When I used your code, I am getting an access denied exception to the filepath containing the XML.

Comment: @clerktech DataGridView has DefaultCellStyle property. Go there and set `NullValue` to `N/A` - thus all nulls will be displayed as `N/A` in grid. If you have *acces denied exception* then probably some other process has locked file. Its hard to tell without details. But thus access to files is not related to xml parsing, I would suggest start new question and add problem details there

Comment: thank you. I will do that now. I appreciate all of your help with my XML issue. I am learning from my lack of knowledge.

Comment: can I send you my email for further questions? I am now getting another issue that states "Cannot implicitly convert type `FileDateTestMethod.FillingLeadDoc` to `object[]`.

Answer (score 1):

Am I wrong assuming you are asking for this:

```
return new object[]
{
(string)documentNode.Parent.Parent.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DocumentIdentification"),
SequenceNode != null ? SequenceNode.Value.Trim() : "NA",
(DateTime?)receivedDateNode.Elements().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name.LocalName == "DateTime"),
descriptionNode != null ? descriptionNode.Value.Trim() : "NA",
registerActionNode != null ? registerActionNode.Value.Trim() : "NA"
};
```

Comment: what is the process for assigning NULL when the element is missing from the XML all together?